# MySql Crear tabla temporal con permiso de solo lectura

Tags: mysql

Necesito traer diferentes resultados de una misma tabla. Para ello utilicé el siguiente código:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nombre_de_tabla_temporal AS 
(SELECT ...)
```

Mi sorpresa es que el usuario que tengo es de sólo lectura y no permite la creación de tablas temporales.

**¿Hay alguna forma de crear una tabla temporal con un usuario de sólo lectura?**
Si no, necesitaría alguna forma alternativa de almacenar la información (en una variable por ejemplo?) para realizar las consultas posteriores.

Sé que un Select ... from (Select ...) serviría, pero queda menos limpio y al realizar cambios es más tedioso

Gracias

P.D.

Ese usuario no puede tener permisos más allá de lectura (las razones no vienen al caso)
Al final lo he apañado guardando los campos como variables de texto y después:

```
SET @campo1 = 'tabla_original.id AS "Primer_Campo",';
SET @campo2 = ...;
...
SET @tabla_temporal = CONCAT ('Select ', @campo1, @campo2, ...);
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @tabla_temporal; 
EXECUTE stmt1
```

De momento con eso me sirve aunque sea un poco farragoso he conseguido lo que quería

Gracias por las respuestas, aunque en mi caso no han servido seguro que a otros usuarios sí ;)

Comment: A qué te refieres con "traer diferentes resultados de una misma tabla"? Hacer varias selects? Que te lo impide? Es decir, en qué te beneficia crear una tabla en vez de usar la que ya existe? Por volumen de datos? Crear una tabla con permisos de lectura no es posible.

Comment: Me refiero a realizar diferentes consultas a la misma tabla nombre_de_tabla_temporal

Answer (score 0):

La solución que yo haría sería crear una vista en mysql con el SELECT que quieras (Una tabla entera, unos datos en concreto...) es más limpio que crear una tabla temporal y no tienes porque cambiar los datos originales.

En tu caso una vista quedaría así:

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] VIEW nombre_vista 
AS consulta_SELECT
```

Comment: Ya lo he probado pero al ser un usuario de sólo lectura no puede crear vistas tampoco
"Error de SQL (1142): CREATE VIEW command denied to user ..."

Comment: ¿Puedes darle permiso de creación de vistas a ese usuario?